# It is possible to use Cuda device pointer in place of a cl::Buffer?

Tags: c++, cuda, opencl

If I have a device ptr from Cuda code, can I use it in a cl::Kernel? Can I pass a cl::Buffer to a Cuda kernel? (lets say you have legacy Cuda code that you want to import into an opencl project, for example?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer, NO.

They are completely different libraries, using a pointer of one into the other will propably crash your app. You can try casting it, but the behaviour is completely unknown.

Comment: That is kinda what I thought, but do you have a reference for the impossibility?

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: Every context in NVIDIA GPUs (be they DirectX, OpenGL, OpenCL, OpenGL) have their own virtual address spaces, managed by the host driver. Pointers and buffers are not portable, except where there are explicit interop APIs which allow mapping of resources. There is no way to have interop between OpenCL and CUDA - everything is different, runtime, compiler. Even PTX assembly code isn't portable (OpenCL and CUDA have different special registers).

Comment: I agree with the answer "NO". However, if you are looking for a way to interop between OpenCL and CUDA you might try using OpenGL in the middle. Both OpenCL and CUDA can create objects (like images) based on OpenGL objects (like textures). You might be able to double-interop your way to OpenCL/CUDA interop. Good luck!